# C# Dual Threading, Thread.IsAlive is false even when this thread didn't finish yet

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I wrote a short Program which searches for empty directories and deletes them.
This process should run in background while a second process should write something to the Console every second so that the user knows the program is still running.
**My problem is** that the whole program stops after about 3 seconds while the processDirectory method didn't even finish.

My **Main Method** which calls a Method (**processDirectory()**) which runs in a second Thread:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread delEmpty = new Thread(() => Thread2.processDirectory(@"C:\Users\Mani\Documents"));

    delEmpty.Start();
    printRunning(delEmpty);

    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\Unauthorized Folders.txt", Thread2.unauthorized);
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\Empty Folders.txt", Thread2.emptyFolders);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

My second Class which stores my **processDirectory** Method which should run in background:

```
public static List<string> unauthorized = new List<string>();
public static List<string> emptyFolders = new List<string>();
public static void processDirectory(string rootPath)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(rootPath)) return;

    foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath))
    {
        try
        {
            processDirectory(dir);
            if (Directory.GetFiles(dir).Length == 0 && Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Length == 0) Directory.Delete(dir, false);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae) { unauthorized.Add(uae.Message); }
    }
}
```

Code for printing something:

```
static async void printRunning(Thread delEmpty)
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;
    for (int cnt = 1; delEmpty.IsAlive; cnt++)
    {
        switch (cnt)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Write("Running.  ");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.Write("Running . ");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.Write("Running  .");
                cnt = 0;
                break;
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    Console.Write("Finished!");
    Console.CursorVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: Purpose of `await` is to release the thread. That is exactly what happening here.

Comment: Ok Thank You! Do you know how I get the same (working) result without async wait?

Comment: Use sync wait: `Thread.Sleep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that you avoid using threads and use an abstraction that deals with your threading issues for you. I suggest making use of Microsoft's Reactive Framework Team's Reactive Extensions (NuGet "System.Reactive") and Interactive Extensions (NuGet "System.Interactive").

Then you can do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rootPath = @"C:\Users\Mani\Documents";

    using (Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"Running{"".PadLeft((int)x % 3)}.")))
    {
        Thread2.processDirectory(rootPath);
    }

}

public static class Thread2
{
    public static List<string> unauthorized = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> emptyFolders = null;
    public static void processDirectory(string rootPath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(rootPath)) return;

        emptyFolders = 
            EnumerableEx
                .Expand(Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath), dir => Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
                .Where(dir => Directory.GetFiles(dir).Length == 0 && Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Length == 0)
                .ToList();

        emptyFolders
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Reverse()
            .ForEach(dir =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.Delete(dir, false);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae) { unauthorized.Add(uae.Message); }
            });
    }
}
```

The key elements here are:

1. the `Observable.Interval` that sets up a timer to display the "Running" message every second.
2. the `EnumerableEx.Expand` which recursively builds the list of folders to be deleted.
3. the `Reverse/ForEach` which runs through the folders to be deleted (in reverse order) and deletes them.

It's important to not that the deleting happens on the main thread - it's just the "Running" message that comes out on the other thread. If needed, though, it would be fairly easy to push the deleting to another thread, but it isn't necessary.

---

To handle the case when `GetDirectories` throws an error, use this code:

```
    Func<string, string[]> getDirectories = dir =>
    {
        try
        {
            return Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
        {
            unauthorized.Add(uae.Message);
            return new string[] { };
        }
    };

    emptyFolders =
        EnumerableEx
            .Expand(getDirectories(rootPath), dir => getDirectories(dir))
            .Where(dir => Directory.GetFiles(dir).Length == 0 && getDirectories(dir).Length == 0)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I really like how it works! But now i have a new problem with your code: The **unauthorizedAccess** exception sometimes occurs when calling the **Directory.GetDirectories(..)** method. For example: 
**The access to the path " C : \ Users \ Mani \ Documents \ My Pictures " was denied .** Do you know how to avoid this error, because i don't see a way how to do it with the code you provided.

Comment: @MartinNiederl - I've added the code you need into the answer.

Comment: Thanks! You're great! :)

Comment: @MartinNiederl - No worries. If you like the answer don't forget to up-vote too.

Answer (score -2):

You can solve the issue by on of two ways:

1. Make your method printRunning run synchronously
2. Add `delEmpty.Join()` so main thread will wait while delEmpty thread finishes

   ```
   delEmpty.Start();
   printRunning(delEmpty);
   delEmpty.Join();
   ```

In case of 1st solution replace the `printRunning` method with the following one

```
static void printRunning(Thread delEmpty)
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;
    for (int cnt = 0; delEmpty.IsAlive; cnt++)
    {
        switch (cnt % 3)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.Write("Running.");
                break;
            case 1:
                Console.Write("Running..");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.Write("Running...");
                break;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        Console.Clear();
    }
    Console.Write("Finished!");
    Console.CursorVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I make brakes between two Console Outputs when I can't use async await? (It's my first time using more than one Thread so I'm sorry for asking silly questions :D)

Comment: Console output is made synchronously no matter if you run it in a separate thread. Didn't pay attention on the printRunning method. Edited your version of the method (see my answer above). I believe that is what you are trying to achieve.